# How to limit breadcrumb trail to site name?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, breadcrumb

I made a page layout in SP2013, and enabled breadcrumbs, but the problem is the trail goes too far, it goes directly to the page name, for example:

```
> Mysite > en > Pages > default
```

but I want it to stop at the site level, so

```
> Mysite > en
```

I found the breadcrumb code in the .html file

```
    <!--MS:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb" runat="server">-->
        <!--SPM:<SharePoint:ListSiteMapPath
            runat="server"
            SiteMapProviders="SPXmlContentMapProvider"
            RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="false"
            PathSeparator=""
            CssClass="ms-breadcrumb"
            NodeStyle-CssClass="ms-breadcrumbNode"
            CurrentNodeStyle-CssClass="ms-breadcrumbCurrentNode"
            RootNodeStyle-CssClass="ms-breadcrumbRootNode"
            NodeImageOffsetX="0"
            NodeImageOffsetY="289"
            NodeImageWidth="16"
            NodeImageHeight="16"
            NodeImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/fgimg.png?rev=23"
            RTLNodeImageOffsetX="0"
            RTLNodeImageOffsetY="312"
            RTLNodeImageWidth="16"
            RTLNodeImageHeight="16"
            RTLNodeImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/fgimg.png?rev=23"
            HideInteriorRootNodes="true"
            SkipLinkText=""/>-->
    <!--ME:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
```

But I am not sure how to change it to fix it. I think I need to modify the sitemapprovider value. I found this page https://ktskumar.wordpress.com/2008/04/14/sharepoint-navigation-providers-part-1/
but I am still not sure.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code instead. Remove `SharePoint:ListSiteMapPat` and add this code:

```
<asp:sitemappath runat="server" sitemapproviders="SPSiteMapProvider,SPXmlContentMapProvider" rendercurrentnodeaslink="false" hideinteriorrootnodes="true">
</asp:sitemappath>
```